# Adding customer-note and removing order-total from table woocomerce UserEnd Orders table

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove "order-total" from the table and adding "customer-note" to the table.

[Table with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl7cU.png)

```
function ts_get_product_name_from_order_item($order_item) {
  $product_id = $order_item['product_id'];
  $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
  if ($product) {
    return $product->get_name();
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', function($columns) {
$new_columns = [
        "order-number" => $columns["order-number"],
        // ...
        "order-date" => __( 'Alta', '' ),
        // 
        "customer-note" => __( 'Paciente', '' ),
        // ...
        "product_name" => __( 'Producto', '' ),
        //...
        "order-status" => __( 'Estado', '' ),
        //
        "order-actions" => $columns["order-actions"],
        // ...
        ];
    
  foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
    if ($key === 'order-status') {
      $new_columns['product_name'] = __('Productos', 'woocommerce');
    }
    $new_columns[$key] = $column;
  }
  return $new_columns;
});
add_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_product_name', function($order_id) {
  $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
  $order_items = $order->get_items();
  foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
    echo ts_get_product_name_from_order_item($order_item);
    echo '<br>';
  }
});
```

I've tried removing it in a separate snippet. Working

```
add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'remove_my_account_order_total' );

function remove_my_account_order_total($order){
  unset($order['order-total']);
  return $order;
}
```

[Working code - only unset total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZdWk.png)